# AS3: Can't move object I spawned, X and Y are "undefined properties"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am using AS3 for the first time for a school assignment, and when I try to move an object I have spawned in the same frame, I get:

*"1119: Access of possibly undefined property y through a reference with static type Class"*

The error appears twice and is referencing this line of code:

```
arrowUp.y += 2;
```

I get the same error if I try to move the object along the X-axis as well.

Full code of the function:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveArrowUp);

function moveArrowUp(event:Event):void
{
    if(arrowUp_exists = true)
    {
    arrowUp.y += 2;
    }
}
```

If I use this same code to move an object that exists on the stage without being spawned with code, it works. If I put a trace within the if statement, it also works correctly.

"arrowUp_exists" is a boolean variable I created at the beginning of the frame so this code wouldn't run until arrowUp was spawned, which I am certain works because of the trace I tested.

All of the coding is being done on the timeline, due to that being how the teacher taught it and marks would be subtracted for not doing that (so I'm not using external classes for code, but I have exported all of my symbols to ActionScript).

Answer (score 0):

According to that error, `arrowUp` is your class (AS linkage name).

So you should create an instance of that class to use it, it's the same as adding an instance from the library to your stage, just it's using code.

You can do like this :

```
var arrow_up:arrowUp = new arrowUp();
    arrow_up.x = 200;
    arrow_up.y = 100;

addChild(arrow_up);
```

For more about `addChild()`, take a look [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChild()), and about objects and classes, from [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/oop-concepts/objects-and-classes.html).

Hope that can help.

Comment: Setting the new arrowUp removed the errors, but when I run the game, it doesn't move at all. Any reason why that would be?

Comment: @Wingwire Your `if` statement should be `if(arrowUp_exists == true){}` because `=` is using for assignment  and `==` for comparison.

Comment: Still not working for some reason. I added `trace("yes");` inside the `if` statement and the output window gets filled with "yes", yet the object refuses to move

Comment: @Wingwire I answered your question according to what you've put and what I can see ! So I don't know why your code is not working because simply I don't know what you have as code ...

Comment: The object spawns just outside of the stage every second, then try to have each move it down as they spawn with this function. That's all that interacts with this object as of right now. It spawns and moves inside separate functions

Comment: Okay I cleaned up the code and unified some variables that I have no idea weren't in the first place, so my mistake there. It moves perfectly as I want it to. Another problem that is happening though is that it moves back up to its original spawn location when the next is added. Is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: The object needs to spawn in the same position every time. Is it possible to move only the new ones to the spawn location, and leave the existing ones to continue on their course?